# 'which' reports one thing, actual command is another

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, which

I am running Ubuntu 12.04, which came with Cmake v 2.8.7.

I had need for a more current CMake, so I downloaded the source for 12.8.12.1, built, and installed it per directions.  The last step, `make install` I ran `sudo`ed.

```
./bootstrap
make
sudo make install
```

Now I want to run it, but I find that the old version is still invoked when I execute `cmake` from the command line:

```
jdibling@hurricane:/$ cd /; cmake --version; which cmake
cmake version 2.8.7
/usr/local/bin/cmake
jdibling@hurricane:/$
```

Odd, I think.  So I `su` and try it from there:

```
root@hurricane:~# cd /; cmake --version; which cmake
cmake version 2.8.12.1
/usr/local/bin/cmake
root@hurricane:/#
```

Why does `which` report the same directory, but `cmake --version` reports different versions?  How can I find where the new `cmake` was actually installed?

As suggested, I ran `type`:

```
jdibling@hurricane:/tmp/cmake-2.8.12.1$ type cmake
cmake is hashed (/usr/bin/cmake)
jdibling@hurricane:/tmp/cmake-2.8.12.1$ sudo su -
root@hurricane:~# type cmake
cmake is /usr/local/bin/cmake
root@hurricane:~#
```

Comment: related: [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `type` command to know what is really under its name, i.e.:

```
type cmake
```

That might be an `alias` that run a different version of `cmake`, or a `function` with a similar behavior or finally a previously `hashed` command that in not any more the first one in your `PATH`, as you experienced.

Comment: `jdibling@hurricane:/tmp/cmake-2.8.12.1$ type cmake
cmake is hashed (/usr/bin/cmake)
jdibling@hurricane:/tmp/cmake-2.8.12.1$ sudo su -
root@hurricane:~# type cmake
cmake is /usr/local/bin/cmake
root@hurricane:~#`

Comment: Precisely. Answer updated.

Comment: I see.  So I guess the question now is why did the cmake installer put the thing in `/usr/local/bin`.  Ah well, I can fix that.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually I take that back.  All I had to do was log back in to my shell.